# Understanding how to run I/O operations on asynchronous FastAPI endpoints

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, fastapi

I have an endpoint defined as asynchronous:

```
@router.post("/upload", status_code=200, response_model=schemas.S3UploadSchema)
async def upload(
    file_name: str,
    data: str,
    s3_client=Depends(dependencies.get_s3_client),
    current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)
):
    uploads3 = await s3_client.upload_fileobj(
        bucket=settings.RESULT_BUCKET,
        key=f"{settings.RESULT_FOLDER}/{file_name}",
        data=data
    )
    if uploads3:
        s3_url = f"https://{settings.RESULT_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/{settings.RESULT_FOLDER}/{file_name}"
        return {"status": "success",
                "image_url": s3_url}
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=400, detail=f"Failed to upload '{file_name}' to S3.")
```

Within this endpoint, I am sending data to S3. However, I have decided to add a CRUD operation to this endpoint like this and you can see the new line:

```
@router.post("/upload", status_code=200, response_model=schemas.S3UploadSchema)
async def upload(
    file_name: str,
    data: str,
    s3_client=Depends(dependencies.get_s3_client),
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
    current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)
):
    uploads3 = await s3_client.upload_fileobj(
        bucket=settings.RESULT_BUCKET,
        key=f"{settings.RESULT_FOLDER}/{file_name}",
        data=data
    )
    if uploads3:
        pattern = crud.create_pattern(db=db, pattern_name=file_name) # new line
        s3_url = f"https://{settings.RESULT_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/{settings.RESULT_FOLDER}/{file_name}"
        return {"status": "success",
                "image_url": s3_url,
                "pattern": pattern}
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=400, detail=f"Failed to upload '{file_name}' to S3.")
```

The session I use while performing this CRUD operation:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
```

I believe that since I'm not using an asynchronous session, this CRUD operation will be executed synchronously. Therefore, it seems like when a request is made to this endpoint, the server will not respond to other requests until the CRUD operation is completed. Firstly, have I fully understood the issue? Am I thinking correctly? If so, what should I do in this situation? Do you have any suggestions?